# WebRTC on iOS: How to establish good video quality?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, webrtc, videochat

I have such media constraints and the quality of video quite good most of time, but sometimes it drops to low quality and never goes back to good.

```
RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[
                                                                                                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"1280"],
                                                                                                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"720"],
                                                                                                    [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"30"]
                                                                                                    ]
                                                                              optionalConstraints:@[]];
```

What is the problem? If it's connected with quality of my current internet connection, yes, sometimes it drops and not so stable, but why in this case the quality of video never goes back to good? 
Could it be connected with TURN / STUN server and low ping and narrow bandwith in their direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before. The cause is downloading has taken most of the bandwidth, so video resolution is dropped to fit the limited uploading bandwidth. To counter this, the bandwidth needs to be restricted in the SDP based on the capture rate. You need to do some string manipulation on the SDP string.

Find the line `c=IN(xxxxxx)` under each media line `m=audio(xxxx)`/`m=video(xxxx)`. Insert a bandwidth spec line after `c=IN(xxxx)`:

```
b=AS:%d
```

`%d` is an integer calculated based on capture rate (video and audio respectively). You should experiment with the number, and check the WebRTC specification for this value.